# Google App Engine not updating in Chrome in Desktop

Tags: google-app-engine

I have deployed a site via Google App Engine. The site is updated for all browsers expect for Chrome on Windows Desktop and Mac. Why is it so happening?

Comment: Have you flushed the backend cache and your browser cache?

Comment: @ojrask how to flush backend cache

Comment: Either in the dev server admin panel or the Google developer console. Search for Memcache.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a backend cache kind of thing. Did you in fact refresh the browser cache? I believe it is Command+Shift+R on mac, Control+F5 on windows. Also are you sure that it's actually not updated, and there's not just an error that only applies to Chrome? If you're really out of solutions, does restarting the computer help? If it is indeed a cache-related problem then restarting the computer should solve it for the time being.

Comment: @MarkLalor I have tried everything but still its not working. One weird thing that is happening is that  if I open the site via incognito it is working perfectly but through the normal chrome it is giving me the older version. (Note: In normal chrome window I have logged in my google account)

Comment: That's pretty bizarre. The only other thing I can think of is to reinstall Google Chrome. You may have even tried that already... that's about all I have off the top of my head :(

Comment: @MarkLalor Finally got the solution. Thanks for your help. SO is a great village :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time breaking my head on this problem finally I got the solution, the problem was very very very silly and irritating

The extensions attached to my browser namely Ad Block was causing the older version to be presented whenever I used to visit the site.

So the solution is:

Disable the extensions and see which silly extension is causing the trouble

Comment: Good for you! Odd stuff.